# Failed to get "Integer Tag" of ImageView and pass in Intent in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, tags

I want to set Tag of ImageView as 1,2,3 .......  and want to retreive that tag onClick and pass it with Intent and retrieve it using Intents in nextActivity and pass to a function But failed to do so....

XML:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/latest_btn_quran_on"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/latest_quran_on"
            android:tag="1"/>
```

ImageView ClickListener :

```
    quranHadeesButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.latest_btn_quran_on);
    quranHadeesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent latestQuranQuesAns = new Intent(GenraltopicActivity.this,GeneralTopicQuestions.class);
            //latestQuranQuesAns.putExtra("clickedTopicid",quranHadeesButton.getTag().toString());
            int id = (Integer) quranHadeesButton.getTag();
            latestQuranQuesAns.putExtra("clickedTopicid",id);
            startActivity(latestQuranQuesAns);
            }
        });
```

GeneralTopicQuestions Activity :

```
    public class GeneralTopicQuestions extends Activity
{ImageView quranOHadeesQuestion1;
Context context;
List<String> questionImagesNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.general_topic_questions);
        context = this;
        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        String clickedTopicId = Integer.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("clickedTopicid"));//string data will contain image file name
        Log.i("clickedTopicid",""+clickedTopicId);
        JamiaBinoriaDBHelper dbhelper = new JamiaBinoriaDBHelper(context);
        dbhelper.open();
        //Integer sampleId = clickedTopicId 
        questionImagesNameList = dbhelper.GetClickedIdImages(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("clickedTopicid"));
        Log.i("questionImagesNameList:",""+questionImagesNameList);
}
}
```

The problem is with this LOC:

```
questionImagesNameList = dbhelper.GetClickedIdImages(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("clickedTopicid"));
```

EDIT LOGCAT:

> 02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at com.jamia.binoria.GenraltopicActivity$1.onClick(GenraltopicActivity.java:28)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
>   02-06 00:03:15.780: E/AndroidRuntime(7564):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Whew is your onClick listner? and do paste your log cat.

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope it will help you.

In place of

> String clickedTopicId = Integer.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("clickedTopicid"));//string data will contain image file name

Use These lines

> String clickedTopicId = ""+getIntent().getIntExtra("clickedTopicid",DEFAULT_IMG_INT_ID);

Comment: but i am passing int to function how can i convert string into int

Comment: have added logacat please see it

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply:
i had not seen ur message.


Intent latestQuranQuesAns = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        //latestQuranQuesAns.putExtra("clickedTopicid",quranHadeesButton.getTag().toString());
        int id = 12;
        latestQuranQuesAns.putExtra("clickedTopicid",id);
        startActivity(latestQuranQuesAns);
In SecondActivity :

String clickedTopicId = ""+getIntent().getIntExtra("clickedTopicid",1);
  //Toast.makeText(this, clickedTopicId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textId)).setText(clickedTopicId);

Its working fine bro.

Comment: Maybe you are doing something wrong in line
 int id = (Integer) quranHadeesButton.getTag();
may getTag return nonInteger String so there also ClassCast Exception occurs.
you have to check where u r setting tag in button.